# Generating bivariate data where x variable is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 and Y is normally distributed with mean 1/x with some noise

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

I used x <- c(runif(100, 0, 1)) to generate 100 x's between 0 and 1.
Now for each of the x's I am trying to generate 10 y's with mean 1/x and variance of 1.
Preferably stored in a matrix and so if I was to plot the 1000 points on y and x, it would look like the graph y = 1/x  + some error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data in a matrix, then you can do

```
x <- runif(100, 0, 1)
y <- sapply(x, function(m) rnorm(10, 1/m, 1))
```

This uses `sapply` to generate 10 normal values for each `x` value.

If you wanted one, two-column, matrix, then maybe

```
points <- do.call("rbind", lapply(x, function(m) cbind(x=m, y=rnorm(10, 1/m, 1))))
```

is what you want. You can plot that with

```
plot(y~x, points)
```